# Tomcat is shutdown when the out of memory

Tags: jpa, tomcat7

We are using a JPA for the entity manager and when the multiple users access the reports at the same time it throwing an exception and getting out of memory exception. Am checked the is there any possibilties to the memory leakage and i have a doubt that we are not clear the entity when we get the data from the database. Please any one help me out for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: How many concurrent requests is the tomcat handling when running into an out of memory error occurs. How big is the average data structure you are loading per user?  How much memory is available for tomcat?

Comment: The memory for the tomcat is the 8 GB. And we are almost fetching the data from the DB for multiple tables. IS it the coding issue. I thought that we are not clear or flush the entity requests when we are fetching data from the DB.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your structure,  representation of the data (html, pdf,...), the amount of data and the number of concurrent requests it is impossible to give you any useful hints.

Comment: @andih The representation of the data using html5 and angular JS, and jpa query for the report like.. 
@Query("select p from PlayerHandDetails  p where \n" +"p.playerId in (select pl.id from Player pl where pl.frachiseMapId in(select c.franchiseId from Commissions c where c.distributorId =:distributorId) )\n" +"and p.endDate between :startDate and :endDate ")
 Page<PlayerHandDetails> getPlayersForDistributorWhereEndDateBetweenAndAllGames(@Param("distributorId") String distributorId, @Param("startDate") Timestamp startDate,@Param("endDate") Timestamp endDate, Pageable pageable);